# adding another condition procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

Here is my procedure..

How can i get add another condition which should satisfy that the updated_time record in the driver_latlong table should be less than 1 minute ??

Here is my procedure

```
BEGIN
SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT (DriverLocation.updated_at - NOW()) as Diff, DriverLocation.updated_at,  NOW(), DriverLocation.AutoId, DriverLocation.DriverId,  
    @dist:= ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(',lat,') ) * cos( radians( DriverLocation.Lat ) ) * cos( radians( DriverLocation.Long ) - radians(',lng,') ) + sin( radians(',lat,') ) * sin( radians( DriverLocation.Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM driver_latlong DriverLocation LEFT JOIN driver_details DriverDetail on DriverDetail.DriverId = DriverLocation.DriverId where DriverLocation.DriverId NOT IN (',Exclude,') AND DriverDetail.IsActive=',1,' AND DriverDetail.IsOnline=',1,'   having distance <=50000.0 ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 1;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just refer the time that MySQL gets i.e., [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

You shall get the records that has the difference that is between 0 and 60 seconds (1 Minute)

You should then add this to your procedure

```
AND (DriverLocation.updated_at - NOW() BETWEEN  0 AND 60 )
```